# Error Retrieving Data on Application Insights

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10, win-universal-app, azure-application-insights

So, I'm facing this problem for more than a week now:

[image: Error retrieving data.]

Anything I can do?

Comment: try opening a support ticket with microsoft

Comment: Did it ever work? Have you tried changing the Time Range?

Comment: Yes it was working since August 1st, it has some thousands of data on it. Changing Time Range doesn't fix unfortunately.

Comment: Posted an answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space symbol seemed to be causing a problem in Safari. This bug is fixed and the fix is deployed, please check again.

Comment: Stil not working, maybe in few hours. There are a lot of errors on the browser console that doesn't appear on Chrome, mainly this one: 'Failed to load resource: Origin [url] is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.'. See: http://pastebin.com/smLUC8Rx

Answer (score 0):

Just found out this error only appears on **Safari**!

So, current workaround:
Use Chrome or Microsoft Edge. Works perfectly.